# How can you tell if if a meal is thawed?

Tags: refrigerator, thawing

I am planning to place a meal (salmon + rice) in a refrigerator after having frozen it.

How can I tell when it's thawed?

Answer (score 2):

Aside from simply feeling the package, a thermometer would be the most accurate way to tell.

Comment: thanks for the response - what temperature range should I be looking for?

Comment: 32F (0C) is the freezing point of water.  Most refrigerators are below 40F (4C), but above 32F (0C).

Comment: so a properly thawed meal should be between 0C - 4C?

Comment: 0C will be frozen.  Above 4C puts you in the danger zone.

Comment: so a properly thawed meal should be between 0C - 4C?

Comment: @nz_21 see above